# Toggle inclusion of text in LaTeX

Tags: latex, customization

I am trying to make a thorough header in LaTeX that will save time later when I write quizzes and tests. I'd like to include solutions to each question in the .tex file, with some flag that toggles whether they appear when compiled.

So in a document like this...

```
\begin{document}

Some question
\solution{ the answer to the question}

\end{document}
```

..the solution would be invisible unless I include a "\showsolutions" flag.

Is there a command I can create that will do this?

Comment: (An answer rather than comment) A more modern solution is to use toogles from `etoolbox` package.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\newif` to create a new if-type construct, and set the default value.

```
\newif\ifshowsolutions
\showsolutionsfalse
```

Then use it in your `\solution` command

```
\newcommand{solution}[1]{\ifshowsolutions #1 \fi}
```

To turn on solutions, use

```
\showsolutionstrue
```